# Entity Framework Core calculated fields based on navigation properties are null. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to store the data of a small football championship in an ASP.NET Core MVC application. There are players who belong to teams and matches with foreign keys for 2 existing teams. This has worked so far, but I've decided to reduce the stored attributes of teams (wins, ties, losses etc.) because they can be calculated from the matches table. So the major thing is that is WAS working successfully with the previous solution.

The exact problem is that the 'HomeTeam' and 'AwayTeam' navigation properties in the Team model class are null in the case there is already one match in the database which is even displayed in the application. So now the leaderboard is full of 0s.

//NAVIGATION PROPERTIES - Team.cs

```
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

    //[InverseProperty(nameof(Match.HomeTeam))]
    public IList<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    //[InverseProperty(nameof(Match.AwayTeam))]
    public IList<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ColorID"), Display(Name = "Shirt color")]
    public virtual Color ShirtColor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MatchDayID"), Display(Name = "Preferred matchday")]
    public virtual MatchDay PreferredMatchday { get; set; }
```

//NAVIGATION PROPERTIES - Match.cs

```
    [Display(Name = "Home"), ForeignKey("HomeTeamID"), InverseProperty(nameof(Team.HomeMatches))]
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Away"), ForeignKey("AwayTeamID"), InverseProperty(nameof(Team.AwayMatches))]
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    public IList<MatchPlayer> MatchPlayers { get; set; }
```

Actually, this is my first complex task and first question on this site but I believe I am close to the solution and hopeful some of you guys can help me with this. Best wishes to all!

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web stack, not a data access library or ORM. This is an EF Core question. Post your code as text, not images that can't be copied and compiled. Don't ask people to re-type your code just to try it

Answer (score 0):

EF Core will not automatically load navigation properties but instead gives you 3 options to load the navigation properties. [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

I would apply Explicit Loading in your case. The DbContext can be injected into your entity object via the constructor. (EF Core will inject this into your class.) And then call

```
_context.Entry(this)
    .Collection(b => b.HomeMatches)
    .Load(); // or LoadAsync if async is possible
```

Answer (score 0):

My God, after 3 hours I found out only Include() methods were missing in the Controller.

```
var teams = await _context.Teams
                .Include(t => t.HomeMatches)
                .Include(t => t.AwayMatches)
                .ToListAsync();
            var orderedTeams = teams.OrderByDescending(t => t.Points)
                                    .ThenByDescending(t => t.GoalDifference)
                                    .ThenByDescending(t => t.Wins)
                                    .ThenByDescending(t => t.GoalsScored);
            return View(orderedTeams);
```

Thank your for the help anyway @verbedr